# VBA - Version System

Tags: vba

I have a visual basic app, and I have a file in my host called version.txt.

I want to connect it to my vba app and whenever I change the number written in version.txt, the app warns the user to download a newer version of the app. How could I do that?

Comment: which is your 'app'? excel, word, other? you could remember last version and check file version each time you consider it's important. you didn't provide much information which could help to make any other suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumes Excel. The constant stays in your app and the value in Version.txt changes.

```
Public Const dVERSION As Double = 6.2

Public Function IsCurrentVersion() As Boolean

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim lFile As Long
    Dim dVer As Double

    sFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Version.txt"
    lFile = FreeFile

    Open sFile For Input As lFile
    Input #lFile, dVer
    Close lFile

    IsCurrentVersion = dVer <= dVERSION

End Function
```